# Remove http client logging handler in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, httpclient

When using the `HttpClientFactory` of .NET Core, is it possible to somehow remove the default `LoggingHttpMessageHandler`?

I expect something like the below but it doesn't seem to exists

```
services.AddHttpClient("minos")
   .RemoveHttpMessageHandler<LoggingHttpMessageHandler>();
```

Answer (score 26):

Just for anyone needing this, I had opened an issue on the GitHub repo, and one of the contributors had replied with the following

```
services.RemoveAll<IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter>();
```

1. **Just Add this line AFTER the adding of the HttpClient**
2. **Make sure to use `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Extensions` namespace**

https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/issues/196#issuecomment-432755765

Comment: a lot of people copy the code without reading a lot, so posting a code that does not work at all and adding an update it is not ideal at all, this is what happened to me and this is why I updated this answer. Anyway, that worked, Thank you

Answer (score 22):

You can configure it in appsettings.json by setting HttpClient's log level to ***none***:

> However, this will also enable informational messages from all other
> components in the System root namespace. Therefore it may be better to
> configure the logging by limiting the configuration to
> “System.Net.Http.HttpClient” so that you only add in the messages from
> the HTTP requests through clients created via the HttpClientFactory:
>
> ```json
>     {
>       "Logging": {
>         "LogLevel": {
>           "Default": "Warning",
>           "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Information"
>         }
>       }
>     }
> ```

https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclientfactory-asp-net-core-logging

Comment: Thanks for that, but I didn't want to remove only the logs, I wanted to remove the whole middleware (or messagehandler) from the pipeline in order to be even more faster. I left a comment on the github and they gave me a solutio which i havent tried yet

Comment: I like this solution better. that way we can change the logging level to error. instead of removing all loging from httpclient completely

Comment: But the question is how to remove it (which could be for any number of valid reasons) not if you like it being there or not :)