# Turn off HttpClient Logging in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, httpclient

I've created a http client in asp.net core3.1. And injected it in via startup and it works fine.

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyClient>();
```

However I can't control it's logging output. Been following the advice here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#logging

I've tried all sorts in my config. It currently looks like this

```
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "System": "Error",
      "System.Net.Http": "Warning",
      "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning",
      "System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyClient.LogicalHandler": "Warning",
      "System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyClient.ClientHandler": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
    }
  },
```

But I keep getting the infomation logs e.g.

```
Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"Received HTTP response after {ElapsedMilliseconds}ms - {StatusCode}","Properties":{"ElapsedMilliseconds":895.4859,"StatusCode":"UnprocessableEntity","EventId":{"Id":101,"Name":"RequestEnd"}

"Level":"Information","MessageTemplate":"End processing HTTP request after {ElapsedMilliseconds}ms - {StatusCode}","Properties":{"ElapsedMilliseconds":932.1484,"StatusCode":"UnprocessableEntity","EventId":{"Id":101,"Name":"RequestPipelineEnd"}
```

The sourcecontext is logging too. And this logs as "SourceContext":"System.Net.Http.HttpClient.MyClient.ClientHandler" which rules out a typing issue in my view

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove http client logging handler in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52889827/remove-http-client-logging-handler-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: The second part in the duplicate is what you want: `services.RemoveAll<IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter>();` - I agree that this is highly annoying

Comment: Yes! That's worked. 

services.RemoveAll<IHttpMessageHandlerBuilderFilter>();

Many thanks