# Reducing HttpClient log verbosity

Tags: c#, .net, logging, dotnet-httpclient, .net-6.0

I'm currently writing a .NET 6 application which makes some REST calls.

For some reason, when these calls are made, HttpClient is logging the following:

```
[15:33:15 INF] Start processing HTTP request GET URL_GOES_HERE
[15:33:15 INF] Sending HTTP request GET URL_GOES_HERE
[15:33:15 INF] Received HTTP response headers after 70.5393ms - 200
[15:33:15 INF] End processing HTTP request after 73.441ms - 200
```

Due to the number of calls I'm making, this is making my logging platform hard to navigate.

I can't find any documentation online as to how I'd go about muting these logs. They seem to be new to .NET 6? At least I haven't seen them before starting this new project.

I found [this github repo](https://github.com/johnkors/MinimalHttpLogger) which solves this problem, however, I'd rather not pull a third-party package in just to silence some logs.

I have other "information" level logs in my application, meaning I'm unable to suppress the entire level.

Is there really no native way to silence these logs from HttpClient?

Comment: See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52889827/1426065). It's about setting the logging level to none, but you can also set it to "warning" or "error" in the `appsettings.json` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to exclude these logs using `Serilog`, which I was already using in the application.

When setting up the LoggerConfiguration, you can apply "filters", like so:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Filter.ByExcluding("SourceContext like '%System.Net.Http.HttpClient%' and @l = 'Information'")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 7):

Log settings are set in your appsettings.json file (or the appsettings.development.json file):

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Changing the Default to "Warning" or "Error" (or higher) will remove the lower-level messages (such as the Information messages you are getting).

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. I’m unable to remove *all* information level logs as there are some important ones I need to keep, I don’t have control over whether they’re information or not. I just want to remove the HttpClient logs mentioned above specifically.

Comment: This answers lacks an important part, the keys under "LogLevel" are namespaces. So by adding `"System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Error"` you can filter out stuff from HttpClient that is below error.

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren you are right. And that addresses Jessica's comment about not wanting to filter out all INF logs.

Answer (score 4):

To set the log verbosity of `HttpClient` specifically, add this line to the `LogLevel` settings:

```
"System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
```

Your `LogLevel` part in the *appsettings.json* file may look like this:

```
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Warning",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
  "System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"
}
```